# Box tree seedlings - what do they look and feel like....?

Tags: trees, boxwood

I purchased, online, seeds advertised as 'Box Tree' as I wanted to grow them myself. I planted them and now am getting the results, but they do not look like Box Tree...?
Can anyone help or validate if they are or not...?  The leaves feel very dry and like sandpaper.

Comment: Please post a photo or two - its hard to say anything much without sight of the seedlings